# USB Tethering App recommendation for Android?

Tags: networking, usb, android

Since 2012 I'd been using an app called EasyTether to tether my laptop to my Android phone when away from home and there were no wireless access points available.  This has worked fine until the released of 22.04LTS.  The Linux driver will not install on this version of Ubuntu and the vendor (Mobile Stream) has not responded to inquiries in months.  I'm afraid this product is now "Abandonware" despite the fact it is still being sold in both Amazon and Google's app stores.  Can anyone recommend a replacement app?  I can't upgrade from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS until this is resolved.

Comment: I was able to use Tethering without any special apps on Ubuntu.  As soon as my phone was set into USB Tethering the network device came right up and I had full access to the internet.

Comment: Abandoned indeed because irrelevant and redundant since many Android versions ago. I've been using the same feature mentioned above since Android 4.something more than a decade ago.

Comment: Interesting,  As I understand it, my plan gives me unlimited data, but if I tether I'm limited to how much data I can tether per month if I use Android's built-in tethering.  EasyTether masked tethering allowing me unlimited data while tethered.  I'll go back and look into this further.

Comment: You can still download the .deb file for Ubuntu and install it from http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.html .  Install it by running `sudo apt install ./easytether_0.8.9_amd64.deb` from the folder you downloaded it to.  It does still work in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: @Terence I think you missed the part in my original post so I'll repeat it for you:  "The Linux driver will not install on this version of Ubuntu and the vendor (Mobile Stream) has not responded to inquiries in months."

Comment: In a recent test I was able to make it work on 22.04.  It complains about SSL version 1.1 as being not installable, but it can be downloaded from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb.html and it was fully able to connect to my phone with EasyTether, albeit was the Lite version that is restricted to HTTP, but it worked.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

@Terrance provided the answer.  You have to install the old SSL driver alongside the EasyTether driver for 20.04LTS and it works!  I was able to connect and surf the web on my test system (running Ubuntu Mate 22.04.1LTS) so I can go ahead and update my laptop safely now.

Comment: Is there a way to combine these two packages into an .appimage file?